# How to change a search engine in Firefox 33.0 in openSUSE 13.2?

Tags: opensuse, firefox, browser, settings

I want to change the search engine in my Firefox to DuckDuckGo. I cannot find such option in the Preferences. From what I remember I've seen such an option in other Linux distributions inside different Iceweasels and Firefoxes.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find it inside the `Preferences`.

The only workaround I've found is to change the search engine inside the `Search` bar.

I believe there is a better way. Otherwise it is not possible to change the default search engine once you hide the `Search` bar using `Customise` (below).

[image]